# about the closure of by pointwise convergence of sequences.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, examples-counterexamples

In the book "Integration Theory" (LNM315,  K.Bichteler, p.65)  a family $\mathcal{F}$ of **real** function is called *full* if it is close by pointwise convergence of dominated (by some element of $\mathcal{F}$) sequences. Given a general family $\mathcal{F}$ of real function its full-closure $\mathcal{F}^\delta$ (the minimal full-family containing $\mathcal{F}$) is calculate by transfinite induction: $\mathcal{F}^0:=\mathcal{F}$, and if $\mathcal{F}^a$ is defined for all $a<b$ let $\mathcal{F}^b$ the set of all pointwise limits of  sequences with element's in $\cup_{a<b}\mathcal{F}^a$ (bounded by some element of this set).

If we consider uniform convergence (instead pointwise convergence) we can do in just one step.

For a topological space $X$ I consider the follow property:

$*)$ Given a  convergent sequence of (real) functions  $f_n$ such that $f_n\to f$ (pointwise) and a family of succession $g_{m,n}$ such that $g_{m,n }\to_m f_n$ (pointwise) then exist monotone function $\alpha,\beta: \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ such that the sequence  $h_j:=g_{\alpha(j), \beta(j)} $  converging (pointwise) to $f$.

If $(*)$ is true then $\mathcal{F}^\delta=\mathcal{F}^1$ i.e. we get $\mathcal{F}^\delta$ in just one step 's.

I'm looking for a example of a topological space $X$ such that the property $(*)$ isn't true.

Comment: This is to some extent related to the question when is $C_p(X)$ a [Frechet-Urysohn space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_space#Fr.C3.A9chet.E2.80.93Urysohn_space). (If you want to find such an example, then $C_p(X)$ must not be Frechet-Urysohn.)

Comment: Some results concerning this property can be found in the book V. Tkachuk: A $C_p$-Theory Problem Book. For example, a characterization of topological spaces $X$ such that $C_p(X)$ is Frechet-Urysohn is given. (This characterization is using $\omega$-covers.) It is also shown that $C_p([0,1])$ is not a Frechet-Urysohn space. See [p.18](http://books.google.com/books?id=EcINw8FHIAoC&pg=PA18) for some basic results. Proofs are given [later in the book](http://books.google.com/books?id=EcINw8FHIAoC&pg=PA121).